# Is DatagramSocket.connect() supposed to stall when called on localhost while listening for a packet?

Tags: java, udp, datagram

In Java, DatagramSocket.connect(InetSocketaddress addr) is supposed to filter all packets except those from that port/address, but when I call that method (while listening for a packet in a background thread), it stalls.

```
DatagramSocket datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket(8000);
InetAddress localAddress = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");//localhost/127.0.0.1
int destinationPort = 7000;
datagramSocket.connect(localAddress, destinationPort); // This stall the program
```

Print statements just before the call to "DatagramSocket.connect" print out but print statements just after the call to "DatagramSocket.connect" do not.

Update:

I am also getting stalling when calling DatagramSocket.disconnect(). With DatagramSocket.connect, the stalling happens whether I specify the parameters as an InetAddress and a port and when I give it the combined InetSocketAddress. Another oddity that if I subclass DatagramSocket and call a synchronized method in the subclass, similar stalling results. The only odd thing about it is there are no other synchronized methods in the entire subclass.

Note about my Java version (Oracle Java 8 downloaded on Ubuntu):

```
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

My Java installation was as follows:
http://tecadmin.net/install-oracle-java-8-jdk-8-ubuntu-via-ppa/

^ Is this a bug in Java or is this stalling on datagramSocket.connect supposed to happen? Can anyone explain this behavior? ^

Comment: Perhaps there is a bug with your print statement instead. e.g. you forgot the newline or otherwise are misdiagnosing the problem.

Comment: No, it's not supposed to stall ever. It has no reason to stall. It doesn't block. It doesn't do anything on the network. It just conditions the local API. Are you sure of your observations?

Comment: Absolutely positively 100% sure that it causes stalling. Even calling DatagramSocket.disconnect() without first calling DatagramSocket.connect causes stalling on my machine. Adding JVM version to description.

Comment: `disconnect()` has no reason to block either. The code you posted doesn't prove your point.

Comment: Another oddity that if I subclass DatagramSocket and call a synchronized method in the subclass, similar stalling results. There are no other synchronized methods in the entire subclass.

Comment: Let me double check that - maybe something else is holding the lock.

Comment: Oh. I think I figured it out. DatagramSocket.receive holds a synchronized lock on the DatagramSocket object. Then when I called DatagramSocket.connect or DatagramSocket.disconnect, those methods were also synchronized, so blocking resulted. I had a receive operation going around on a background thread.

Comment: Pointless to start the receive before the connect.

Comment: The background thread was receiving in a loop and putting everything it received into a queue for multiplexing. I just thought that I could connect mid-receive and change the course of which packets will be accepted for future receive operations.

Answer (score 0):

I have a hunch:

DatagramSocket.receive holds a synchronized lock on the DatagramSocket object. Then when I called DatagramSocket.connect or DatagramSocket.disconnect, those methods were also synchronized, so blocking resulted. You had a receive operation going around on a background thread, and this may explain why blocking also occurred on another synchronized method call that you introduced in a subclass of DatagramSocket. This explanation may not be correct (contingent on whether or not the connect and disconnect methods are synchronized on the DatagramSocket object), but it is the most logical one I have so far.

Comment: Fixed. It now mentions listening for packet in background thread.

Answer (score 0):

Your diagnosis / hunch is plausible (as per your Answer).  You should be able to confirm it by attaching a debugger to see what threads are holding what locks when your application locks up.

But I think it points to a real problem in the way you are using datagram sockets. A datagram socket is an inherently single-threaded object.  By design.  If you try to use the socket from multiple threads *simultaneously*, it is liable to lock up.

On the face of it, what you are doing seems completely unnecessary.  If you have a background thread already doing a receive, then why would you need to connect it?  It is already connected!

I take it that you are trying to use `DatagramSocket.connect` calls from another thread to make an on-the-fly change to the remote IP/port that the other thread is `DatagramSocket.receive`-ing from.  It won't work.  It is not possible at the OS syscall level, and therefore not in Java either.  What you need to do is one of the following:

- Configure the background thread to listen for all incoming datagrams, using a wildcard address, etc.  Then process, dispatch or discard, depending on what you are expecting.
- Configure multiple background threads each with their own datagram socket.  (Or one thread and multiple sockets, and use non-blocking I/O and the NIO selector mechanism to multiplex ...)
- Figure out how to unblock the `receive` before doing the re-connect.  (Not sure how you would do that, but sending an `interrupt` to the background thread might work.  A `close` will unblock it too, but that would destroy the `DatagramSocket` object.)

Comment: It isn't connected until you call `connect()`, but you can use a UDP socket in that state: in fact this is the normal usage. I'm sure it is possible to call `connect()` during `recv()` in anther thread at the OS level,  but not necessarily so as to affect the current receive, but why you would do this in another thread as opposed to between receives is a mystery.

Comment: @EJP - The point is that a `recv` does an implicit connect (to "anything") if you haven't done so already with a `connect`.  To be honest, I haven't checked what happens if you do a `connect` during a `recv`, but if it did cause a "re-connect" that would be problematic ...